# MPAndroidChart - First marker on line chart not being centered

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm trying to display a linechart with a Custom Marker class that's centered on the highlight line.

`.setHighLightColor(Color.WHITE);`

I can't figure out why only the first marker is not being centered correctly, while all the others are.

First item (not correctly centered):

[image]

Last item (and all the other items in between are correctly centered):

[image]

Here's my custom marker class:

```
public class ChartMarker extends MarkerView {

    public ChartMarker(Context context, int layoutResource) {
        super(context, layoutResource);
    }

    @Override
    public MPPointF getOffset() {
        return new MPPointF(-(getWidth() / 2f), -getHeight() / 2f);
    }
}
```

Also using the attributes:

```
        lineChart.setMinOffset(0f);
        lineChart.getAxisLeft().setEnabled(false);
        lineChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
        lineChart.getXAxis().setEnabled(false);
        lineChart.setNoDataText(null);
        lineChart.setScaleEnabled(false);
        lineChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
        lineChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
```

This has me really lost to why it isn't working as expected. I tried googling for similar problems, but couldn't find any answer.

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail so someone could generate a simple chart showing the same issue? (e.g. including a simple data set and all code used to set up the chart).

Comment: This is a long shot, I was just looking at the source code; I suppose that for the first point you might get in [this situation](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/components/MarkerView.java#L94) which means that it considers that the marker simply doesn't fit to the left; I'd experiment by calling  `setMinOffset` with a value larger than marker half-width, or explicitly setting the offset by calling `setOffset` or `setExtraOffsets`.

Comment: @TylerV & kikon Thanks for the help, appreciate it. Yeah the setExtraOffsets makes it work by adding an extra 4dp, but you end up with that spacing on the chart, which I don't quite like. I ended up adding a listener on the linechart instead that changes the drawable to a similar one where the margin is -5 to the left when the line indicator as at the first data point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding extra margin to the left of the chart fixes the problem as `kikon` mentioned.

`lineChart.setExtraLeftOffset(4f);`

but if you don't want that extra spacing for the entire view, you can add a `listener` onto your `LineChart`.

So you would have two drawables, one drawable for all the values that are not `index 0`. And a second drawable for `index 0` that has a `marginStart` of negative dp.

`Drawable for all datapoints NOT of index 0`

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_white_holo_circle" />
```

`Drawable for datapoint index of 0`

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="-5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_white_holo_circle" />
```

```
 private final OnChartValueSelectedListener valueListener = new OnChartValueSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueSelected(Entry e, Highlight h) {
    
            int index = (int) h.getX();

            if (index == 0) {
                lineChart.setMarker(chartMarkerIndexZero);
            } else {
                lineChart.setMarker(chartMarker);
            }

            lineChart.invalidate();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected() {

        }
    };
```

Hopefully this helps someone!